# Why is this python script running in background consuming 100 % CPU?

Tags: scripts, python, clipboard

I want to run a simple python script in the background that reads text from the clipboard and prints it out. Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Tkinter

last_clipboard = ""

def get_clipboard():
  global last_clipboard
  root = Tkinter.Tk()
  root.withdraw() # Hide the main window (optional)
  text_in_clipboard = root.clipboard_get()
  if text_in_clipboard != last_clipboard:
    last_clipboard = text_in_clipboard
    print last_clipboard


while True:
  get_clipboard()
```

This is working as expected but it consumes too much CPU (100% CPU).

How can I make it work correctly without consuming that much?

Comment: If at all supported by the framework you're using, use event-based code to detect changes in the clipboard rather than a loop. There's a difference between getting the clipboard continuously until it changes or to listen to the system telling you that it changed.

Comment: @dessert I haven't ever done it in python, but here seems to be a solution with GTK: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25961646/985296 (doesn't mention any platform dependency).

Comment: @jpmc26 & dessert Looks like a meta discussion, feel free to take it up there. Definitely a good idea to get this cleared up for [meta-tag:scope].

Comment: @dessert Open a meta thread if you and JPMC want to discuss whether this is on/off topic.  Please do not use comments for this argument.  (Comment cleanup complete, topic locked for a week pending your Meta discussion but to also stop the comment argument)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You forgot the `time.sleep()` in your `while` loop, according to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10926766/6164712) sleeping for 0.2s is a good compromise between polling frequency and CPU load:

```py
import time

while True:
  get_clipboard()
  time.sleep(0.2) # sleep for 0.2 seconds
```

Checking the clipboard every 0.2 seconds seems easily often enough; if you want less CPU load you can even increase this value – few users change the clipboard content from one second to another.

Note that in general polling in a loop as often as that is not considered good design. A better approach would be to act on the *event* of changing the clipboard content, an example for GTK can be found [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25961646/6164712).

#### Further reading

- [linuxconfig.org article on Python While Loops](https://linuxconfig.org/python-while-loops)
- [cyberciti.biz article on `time.sleep()`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-sleep-command-syntax-example/)
- [blog article on How To Make Python Wait](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-make-python-wait) discussing different ways, some of which are much more elaborate and flexible than the static `time.sleep()`

Comment: You could make the sleep interval shorter without really affecting the CPU time used. I found on my Mac: 0.01 s: 69%, 0.02 s: 43%, 0.05 s: 25%, 0.1 s: 14%, 0.2 s: 7%. 0.5 s: 3%

Comment: Polling still sucks because it keeps waking up this process polluting CPU caches and so on.  [As discussed in comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143959/why-is-python-script-running-in-background-consuming-100-cpu#comment1897976_1143959) much better to wait for notification of a clipboard change.

Comment: @dessert: If I knew the answer, I would.  I merely suggest mentioning in your answer that waking up every 0.2 seconds is still not considered a *good* design, and looking for a non-polling approach would be much better.  But for a one-off hack that is only going to run on one computer, sure it's not horrible, and is probably good enough.

Answer (score 27):

I finally make it work a without loop. This is the code:

I had to install few modules: `sudo apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi, sys
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

last_clipboard = ""

def callBack(*args):
  global last_clipboard
  new_clipboard = clip.wait_for_text()
  if new_clipboard != last_clipboard:
    last_clipboard = new_clipboard
    print("new Clipboard")
    print(new_clipboard)

clip = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
clip.connect('owner-change',callBack)
Gtk.main()
```

feel free to choose the solution that fits for you.

Comment: Oooh… Why are you requesting `clip.wait_for_text()` twice?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 you are right I edited ... tanks

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Doesn't everyone copy twice *just* to be sure?

Answer (score 16):

You are running the thing in a `while True:` loop! That means that the CPU is *constantly* running your loop. Just add a small pause there and you should see the CPU usage drop precipitously:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Tkinter
import time

last_clipboard = ""

def get_clipboard():
  global last_clipboard
  root = Tkinter.Tk()
  root.withdraw() # Hide the main window (optional)
  text_in_clipboard = root.clipboard_get()
  if text_in_clipboard != last_clipboard:
    last_clipboard = text_in_clipboard
    print last_clipboard

while True:
  get_clipboard()
  time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I was intrigued by this project so wrote a bash script for those more comfortable in that environment:

```
#!/bin/bash

xclip -o -sel clip > /tmp/LastClip

while true ; do 

    xclip -o -sel clip > /tmp/NewClip
    diff -q /tmp/LastClip /tmp/NewClip > /tmp/DiffClip
    if [[ -s /tmp/DiffClip ]] ; then
        cat /tmp/NewClip    # For testing dump to screen instead of printing
        cp -a /tmp/NewClip /tmp/LastClip
    fi
    sleep 1.0

done
```

It does require Xorg's `xclip` package:

```
sudo apt install xclip
```

It's dumping clipboard contents to screen using `cat` command. If you want hard copy instead replace `cat` with `lp` and specify your printer name, orientation and possibly "fit to page" option.

You will see a bit of lag to screen because I choose `sleep 1.0` which would be unnoticeable with a printer and still faster than people can highlight text and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

If you copy the exact same highlighted text to the clipboard it doesn't trigger a difference. One letter more or less will trigger a response.